Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service .Net 8
I am working on an application I have created an API using dotnet ef command line. I have added multiple layers. Now the issue I am facing is to add migrations. Below is the error message and code I have written.

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'CoffeeShopContext'. The
exception 'Unable to resolve service for type
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[DataLayer.Data.ContextManager.CoffeeShopContext]'
while attempting to activate
'DataLayer.Data.ContextManager.CoffeeShopContext'.' was thrown while
attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported
at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Program.cs
using CoffeeShopAPI.DbIntializer;
using CoffeeShopAPI.ServiceManager;
using DataLayer.Data.ContextManager;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<CoffeeShopContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


builder.Services.AddApplicationServices();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapControllers();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CoffeeShopContext>();
    db.Database.Migrate();
    DbInitializer.Initialize(db);
}


app.Run();

Database Context
 public class CoffeeShopContext: DbContext
 {
     public CoffeeShopContext(DbContextOptions<CoffeeShopContext> options)
          : base(options)
     {

     }

     public DbSet<CoffeeShop> CoffeeShops { get; set; }    
 }

The database context is in the separate class library. DataLayer > Data > Context Manager.


How do you try to run migrations?

Can you share your DbInitializer.Initialize(db) method.

This question is similar to: 'Unable to resolve service for type ¨Microsoft.entityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions¨1[LibraryData.LibraryContext] while attempting to activate. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
